# How to make list-menu display when it have class active?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list-menu").hide();
  $(".head-list a").click(function() {
    $(".list-menu:visible").slideUp('slow');
    $(".head-list").removeClass('active-menu');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active-menu').next().slideDown('slow');
    return false;
  });
  if ($(".list-menu ul li").hasClass('active')) {
    $(".list-menu").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="head-list"><a href="">Puchase</a></div>
<div class="list-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="<?php if($page == 'home'){ echo 'active';} ?>"><a href="customer_list.php">Purchase</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Purchase List</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Purchase3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Purchase4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Purchase5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I Wanna it to display the `.list-menu` that have `ul li` class `active` only.

Thank You for your answers.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? It seems like to be worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add each loop for multiple li.
in your code its only consider last li.
Last li don't have active class.
below is reference code for each loop with li.

```
$( "list-menu ul li" ).each(function( index ) {
 if($(index).hasClass('active'))
 {
   $("index").show();
 }
 else
 {
 $("index").hide();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You can use it

```
$page=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
<li  class="menu-dropdown <?php   
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])=="home.php"){ echo 'active'; } ?> ">
```

Hope it will work properlly

Answer (score 0):

For convenience I would first hide .list-menu using:

```
$(".list-menu").css('display', 'none');
```

Then instead of this:

```
if ($(".list-menu ul li").hasClass('active')) {
        $(".list-menu").show();
}
```

I would run the selector in a loop to check for the class named 'active' as so:

```
 $(".list-menu ul").each(function(e){
    if( $(this).hasClass('active')) {
         $(".list-menu").css('display', 'block');
         $(this).show();             
      }else{
         $(this).hide();
      }
});
```